# Cannot install Bootstrap using npm install bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried installing bootstrap using npm ("npm install bootstrap") but couldn't use bootstrap in my web page. However can't we use only the bootstrap CDN only in my html file?

Comment: What error do you get while `npm install bootstrap`, you can also use CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If NPM adds bootstrap to your server, you will still need to reference it in the web page you are serving out.

It's likely it put the files in something like

```
stylesheets/bootstrap.css
```

inside the webpage your serving (jade/html) you'll still need the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Note where the href points to. If you already have this, you may be pointing to the wrong directory.

Also yes, you can just use a copy/paste from a CDN such as:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

**EDIT:**
Bootstrap also contains javascript files, which you will also need to use,
this could be somewhere like

```
javascripts/bootstrap.js
```

or again, you can just use a copy/paste from a CDN:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I can't give more details without knowing what your problem really is, I was mostly taking a shot in the dark. Start by answering Luzan Baral's question. Was there an error given when you used NPM to install bootstrap? Also give a copy paste of what the code for your web page looks like, and possibly show what your servers file directory looks like if you're intent on serving the bootstrap files yourself.